# Struts 2 properties over static fields?

Tags: java, performance, struts2, static, javabeans

I have been looking for this but found nothing.

Which are advantages of Struts2 properties over Java static fields?, considering that both keep only string values, that the java static fields are final, that Java (`final`) `static` fields are in a separate `Constants.java` file and that both cases would apply only for the backend.

Any answer (performance, project organization, etc.) would be appreciated.

Comment: Please, take in consideration that I already thought about the String objects been created and stored in the pool of String objects.

Comment: Which are Struts2 properties, which java static fields, where do you use them, etc... I (we, probably) can't understand your question as it is now :/

Comment: Sorry, here are known just as "properties" (as they actually are), but what I should have said is "resource bundle"; as I said, they only would be used in the back-end (call it only struts actions for this example) and java static fields would be String constants defined by the programmer, to be clearer, these would have the exactly same values as the "properties" in the resource bundle, hope this clarifies the question.

Comment: Aaah ok. Then the answer is: you will need to recompile and redeploy the project when tomorrow you will discover that the super-immutable-final-static field that you was sure won't be changed EVER... will need to be to changed :)

Comment: Thanks for your comment Andrea, I considered the devmode, but this would apply only for myself (while developing).

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but changing bundles without development mode wouldnt need a recompile and redeploy too?.
Do you know any other concern I should consider?

Comment: If you need to change a constant in a class, you will always need to compile. If your constant comes from, for example, the database, you will never need to compile. If your constant comes from a properties file, depending on the policies of your Company, you may edit it directly in production, or need to re-deploy the entire package (through test, pre-prod, prod)...

Comment: Thanks for the repply Andrea, I wasnt (and will not) taking in consideration a data base approche for this case yet.
I created the thread because I have always recompile when modifing my bundles (not only with struts), but as this is a self development so I still dont have a prod enviroment.
So here is another question that may help, is there a way to see the changes on a resource bundle refelcted on back/front-end without recompile and redeploy (and ofcourse without devmode on)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Static final fields are always constant, it's used with the purpose *unmodifiable* at runtime, resource bundles are reloadable at runtime, and therefore *modifiable*, so the values of the keys could change depending on which bundle is used to search in.

Struts2 uses a hierarchy of such bundles, per action class, package, global resource, etc. Example of such usage is `getText()` used in [localization](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/localization.html).

It searches the hierarchy of bundles to get a simple value for the given key. The `i18n` tag even loads the resource bundle dynamically by the user.

Other example is a struts configuration `struts.properties` that could be overridden by the user constants. Without it using a framework would not be possible.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Roman. I saw that Spring has a way to reload bundles, but as I am working with struts I dont want to add Spring just for this issue.
Soo,is there a way to reload resource bundles with struts2 ?

Comment: `LocalizedTextUtil.reloadBundles()`

Comment: @Zale Notice, that if you have `devMode` is on Struts reloads bundles and configuration on every request.

Comment: thanks to point it, but as I said to Andrea above, i was looking for a way to do it without devmode. But as you suggested reloadBundles works, thanks!